# plot.new has not been called yet for qqline

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a `qqline` plot but I'm having consistent issues getting the following error:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

This is what I tried:

```r
plot(allEffects(model1))
dotplot(ranef(model1, condVar = TRUE))
r_int <- ranef(model1)$ElkID$`(Intercept)`
qqnorm(r_int)
qqline(r_int)
```

Everything worked fine except for `qqline(r_int)`, where I was greeted with the same error:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. List all non-base R packages you are using.

Comment: A wild guess:  `dotplot` is defunct and deprecated, and most likely is fouling up the apparent existence of a plot window.  Use the recommended `dotchart`   .  In fact, I tried this and had no problem with `qqline`.  Make sure your version of R and all libraries are up to date.

Comment: I will try dotchart now, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.